# Android Thread Instantiation

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, thread-safety

Here's a question:
In Android Code, if I have declared an Asynchronous task:

IMPORTANT EDIT: All of these tasks are being executed via executor in parallel.  I am not executing them serially, in which case some of these answers would be obvious.

```
AsynchronousTask task1 = new AsynchronousTask();
task1.execute();
```

And I instantiate another task overtop of that task before it completes:

```
task1 = new AsynchronousTask();
```

Does the old task finish its work, or does it get picked up by garbage collection?

---

If I have created a listener that is waiting for the finish of task1:

```
FinishListener finishListener = new FinishListener()
{
    //do stuff
}
AsynchronousTask task1 = new AsynchronousTask(finishListener);
task1.execute();
```

and I override task1 in this manner and execute it:

```
task1 = new AsynchronousTask(finishListener);
task1.execute()
```

will the listener trigger on the finish of the old task1 or the new task1?

---

Does this change if I reinstantiate the listener?

```
FinishListener finishListener = new FinishListener()
{
    //do stuff
}
AsynchronousTask task1 = new AsynchronousTask(finishListener);
task1.execute();
finishListener = new FinishListener()
{
    //do different stuff
}
task1 = new AsynchronousTask(finishListener);
task1.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling execute, you're executing them serially, because that's how Android does AsyncTasks.  To execute them in parallel, you must call executeOnExecutor(AsycTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,params);

But to answer your questions, if you did have parallel execution:

1)Overwriting a variable does not kill the thread.  It will continue to run in the background

2)Both.  Both threads were passed the same listener.  Which will happen first is a race condition

3)In this case the old listener will be called when the old thread finishes and the new listener will be called when the new thread finishes.  Which of those happens first is a race condition.

Comment: Agreed on all 3 points, however OP does mention using an executor to run the tasks in parallel - even though he doesn't show how (if?) that's properly configured.

Comment: It does, what I said is technically only true for 1.6 and 3.0+.  For 2.x they truly ran in parallel.  I was overly simplifying, assuming he was targetting newer devices.